# Linq Query, asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linq

I read this somewhere, and i was just trying to figure out, what this does.
I know it is a LINQ query, but ater the 'in clause', i see some text, which i am unable to understand, 
Usually, we write a table name here or some source like array/generics.
can anyone please explain me.

```
var youShould = from c
  in "3%.$@9/52@2%35-%@4/@./3,!#+%23 !2#526%N#/-"
  select (char)(c^3<<5);
```

The value in the youShould should be some char value, but i am unable to figure out exactly.

Answer (score 2):

`"3%.$@9/52@2%35-%@4/@./3,!#+%23 !2#526%N#/-"` is just a `string` and the LINQ query iterates over its characters.

The select applies a [bitwise exclusive-OR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx) and some bit shifting. It outputs a enumerable containing some characters. When you call this:

```
Console.WriteLine(youShould.ToArray());
```

You will see the actual message.

Comment: can u pls explain the o/p ?

Comment: In classic C a string was just a array of chars, this is nothing else. If you want to know what `c^3<<5` does, please visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx

Comment: @user3718715: Need more thoughts to explain this code?